# NgForOf<string | string[], NgIterable<string | string[]>>

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor, angular-ng-if

I have a data type:

```
export interface TYPE_A {
  valueType: TYPE_A_VALUE_TYPES;
  value: string | string[];
}

export enum TYPE_A_VALUE_TYPES {
  singleValue = "singleValue",
  multiValue = "multiValue",
}
```

And, I using `TYPE_A` in the component for `@Input`:

```
@Input() datas: TYPE_A[] = [];
```

And this is my HTML code:

```
<div class="feildContainer" *ngFor="let data of datas">
    <div class="singleFeild" *ngIf="data.valueType == 'singleValue'">
         ...
    </div>
    <div class="multiFeild" *ngIf="data.valueType == 'multiValue'">
        <other-component *ngFor="let dataValue of data.value"></other-component>
    <div>
</div>
```

I getting this error in `vscode`:

```
NgForOf<string | string[], NgIterable<string | string[]>>.ngForOf: NgIterable<string | string[]> | null | undefined
```

I understand the logic of this error, But I'm looking for the best solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a discriminated union as your type:

```
export interface TYPE_A_SINGLEVALUE {
  valueType: TYPE_A_VALUE_TYPES.singleValue;
  value: string;
}
export interface TYPE_A_MULTIVALUE {
  valueType: TYPE_A_VALUE_TYPES.multiValue;
  value: string[];
}

export enum TYPE_A_VALUE_TYPES {
  singleValue = "singleValue",
  multiValue = "multiValue",
}
```

Then, when you want to use the `value` item, you first check the `valueType` against one of the two possible values, and the compiler will know that you want to refer to either the single or multivalued item and assume accordingly. After an `if` of `valueType` `value` won't be `string | string[]`, but `string` or `string[]` as checked.